# Random bursts of CPU usage from Safari for no reason on macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, safari

I’m seeing intermittent random bursts of 100% CPU usage from the Safari process even with all windows closed and all plugins disabled. How can I debug this/know what’s causing this?

I have tried checking every logfile I could find in the Console and don’t see anything obvious.

I’m using macOS Ventura 13.0.1 (22A400) and Safari Version 16.1 (18614.2.9.1.12). I’m not sure if this related to the recent Ventura update but it started *after* the upgrade.